# Variable size matrix in MySQL

Tags: mysql, matrix

I am building an application where users can sign up and then challenge each other (any other). When user 1 has challenged user 2, the score that exists between them is updated and stored (default score is 1 towards each other user). Mutually, user 2 can challenge user 1 and this updates another score.

The simplest way to represent this information is a n*n matrix (with a blank diagonal bcs you don't have a "score" against yourself). My question is : how do you store it using MySQL ? I was thinking of a table with 3 columns : challenger, challenged, score, but that would result in a n² size and such an exponential factor seems inappropriate for such a simple request. Is there another, intended way to handle matrixes with MySQL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial idea seems right.
BTW n² is quadratic, not exponential.

MySQL should deal just fine with this.

```
CREATE TABLE score (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  player1_id integer NOT NULL,
  player2_id integer NOT NULL,
  score_p1 integer NOT NULL,
  score_p2 integer NOT NULL,
  chal_date date KEY NOT NULL,
  /*UNIQUE KEY p1p2 (player1_id, player2_id),*/
  FOREIGN KEY p1 (player1_id) REFERENCES player.id 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY p2 (player2_id) REFERENCES player.id 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
 Engine=InnoDB;
```

Note that you only create a row when an actual challenge has taken place and a score needs to be recorded. So you will have exactly one row per challenge. If the same players can challenge each other more then once you should remove the unique key p1p2.

**Usage examples**

Now if you want to know how many points a player has scored you do

```
SELECT ifnull(sum(a.score_p1),0) + ifnull(sum(b.score_p2),0) AS total_score 
FROM player
INNER JOIN score a ON (a.player1_id = player.id) 
INNER JOIN score b ON (b.player2_id = player.id)
WHERE player.id = 587;
```

If you want to know all the players a player has challenged you do

```
SELECT score.player1 as opponent FROM score 
WHERE score.player2 = 587
UNION ALL
SELECT score.player2 as opponent FROM score
WHERE score.player1 = 587;
```

If you do a small trick and add the following trigger, you can force that
player1.id < player2.id

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER bi_score_each BEFORE INSERT ON score FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE temp integer;

  /*Force player1.id to always be smaller than player2.id*/
  IF new.player1_id > new.player2_id THEN BEGIN
    SET temp = new.player1_id;
    SET new.player1_id = new.player2_id;
    SET new.player2_id = temp;
  END; END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER;
```

Now you can simplify your query to see the cumulative score between two players.

```
@p1:= 578;
@p2:= 789;

SELECT sum(score.score_p1) as score_p1
  ,sum(score.score_p2) as score_p2
FROM score 
WHERE score.player1_id = if(@p1<@p2,@p1,@p2) 
  AND score.player2.id = if(@p1>@p2,@p1,@p2);
```

Use the following query to select all players a player has battled with the scores

```
  SELECT score.player2_id as opponent_id
    ,sum(score.score_p2) as opponent_score
    ,sum(score.score_p1) as player_score
    ,p2.name as opponent_name
    ,p1.name as player_name
  FROM score
  INNER JOIN player p2 ON (p2.id = score.player2_id) 
  INNER JOIN player p1 ON (p1.id = score.player1_id)
  WHERE player1_id = 587
  GROUP BY player2.id
UNION ALL
  SELECT score.player1_id as opponent_id
    ,sum(score.score_p1) as opponent_score
    ,sum(score.score_p2) as player_score
    ,p1.name as opponent_name
    ,p2.name as player_name
  FROM score
  INNER JOIN player p2 ON (p2.id = score.player2_id) 
  INNER JOIN player p1 ON (p1.id = score.player1_id)
  WHERE player2_id = 587
  GROUP BY player1.id
```

Hopes this gives you an idea of what is possible.

Comment: they can challenge more than once but it solely updates the score they had before (thus not creating a new row), so I should keep this key, right ?
oh and in your mind, what was the score_p2 for ? because there will be a reciprocal row somewhere in the table where one could see the score between p2 and p1 (different from p1 and p2), wouldn't this column be redondant then ?

Comment: @user, well if two people battle it out then the score will always be something like 0-2 10-5 or something like that. i.e. both players can score points. Storing these points independently from each other makes no sense, as the outcome of the match can only be known when seeing the two score together.

Comment: hehe tahnks a lot, that certainly gives me an idea of what I still have to learn from MySQL ;) I tend to do all the logics in PHP but I must be wrong.     
Also, why innoDB ?

Comment: InnoDB has foreign keys, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key and: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

Your table idea looks good. If the default score is 1 you don't have to store it in the database. Having 1000 users with no challenges would give you a table consisting of 0 rows, taking almost no space at all. You dont need to reserve space, your table is as big as many challenges you put in it. But if all users have challenges with all other users you will still need O(n²) space unless your scores have some special rules making it possible to dynamically count the score based on other variables.